# PC recognizes keyboard pcb only as FT232R usb UART but doesnt see atmega32a behind it

Tags: uart, atmega, ftdi, firmware, keyboard

I made my own pcb design for mechanical keyboard. When I wanted to test it, both mac and windows system recognize only FTDI ft232rl chip on pcb but not atmega32a behind it that controls whole keyboard. I installed all ftdi drivers but nothing changes.
What should I do or try next?

-rgb diodes are working, I mean they flash white light, probably feeling 5v usb input, but in firmware default color is white also.

Comment: Did you set the correct VID/PID, etc. in the FT232RL?

Comment: Do you mean in code or by driver from ftdi website? If you mean in-code I do not have any line that specify anything about ft232rl.

Comment: The FTDI driver package includes a tool for editing the EEPROM.

Comment: FTDI FT232RL is an USB serial interface chip. It does not understand how to be a keyboard, no matter if VID/PID are changed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can make a FTDI chip or anything behind it look like an USB keyboard.

It is a USB UART chip and thus with FTDI drivers it will look like an USB serial port, in all operating systems, be it Windows, Mac, Linux, FreeBSD or any other OS.

So since it is a serial port, you can talk to the ATMega via the serial port. There is no way the OS or FTDI drivers can know what you have connected to the FTDI and how to communicate with it.

Comment: So basically, this configuration should work, but firmware compiled without any problem and it was flashed on atmega32a via avrdude also from the first try. So what do you suggest me to do now? To take off atmega from pcb and flash another firmware or...?

Comment: What is it that you intend to do with the ATMega32, what do you want to communicate it with, over the FTDI serial port? Due to the FTDI chip, it will never look like a keyboard to the PC, it will be a serial port.

Comment: I'd like to understand better why this was downvoted? I hope there is a real reason behind it.

Comment: I don't know who flagged your comment.

Comment: When I connect keyboard pcb, leds light up, but when I try to imitate switch press with twissers it doesnt print 'a,b,c,...' on monitor, like it doesnt know that the key is being pressed

Comment: Connection is in this order Atmega32a(RxD / PD0 to TXD on ft232rl and TxD / PD1 to RXD on ft232rl over 1kOhm R, DTR from ft232rl connected to reset of atmega and ft232rl pins 14 and 15 connected to usb C over 22Ohm resistors). So USB-c to ftdi then ftdi to atmega32a and atmega32 to leds and switch matrix

Comment: As @Justme has already explained, it's not possible with this hardware. You can write your own application on PC which can listen to serial port and detect / use key presses. But there is no way for it to work as a regular keyboard. You need a USB capable uC and a firmware implementing USB HID protocol.

Comment: I have said many times that the FTDI FT232RL will not show up as a keyboard to your computer, but as a serial port, so you cannot type keys like you can on a keyboard. If you open up the serial port with a terminal program, you should see serial data sent from the ATMega.

Comment: Maybe some kind of virtual HID software running on PC, which listens to serial port and somehow mimics a USB HID device... I'm not sure if it's possible, but definitely it's not the proper way to do it.

Comment: Generally I thought that that chip can make communication between ATMega32a and USB-C like ATMega32u4 that comes with usb enabled communication, but it was easier to take ATMega32a-PU from DIP-40 and reprogram it then desoldering tqfp-44 each time. Then I read about ft232rl that makes this kind of communication so I put it in schematics

Comment: Include pin headers for programming / debugging interface in your PCB design, so that you don't need soldering for firmware updates.

Comment: That is solution yes, but is there anything I can do with this one without designing and ordering new board, because I’m already in “nice” money investment loss

Comment: No, the FTDI chip cannot pretend to be a keyboard when connected between a MCU and PC. You can develop and test the ATMega32 program via the serial port provided by FTDI. The ATMega32U has a built-in USB peripheral device which can be programmed to look like anything you want to the PC - including a standard USB HID keyboard.

Comment: I understand that, but there is no hardware error only with .hex that is flashed. Also I did it directly on mcu that was without bootloader only with usbasp. So the problem is i guess with hex

Comment: No, this IS a hardware problem. You can't do anything about it.

Comment: No hex file can make it look like a USB keyboard. The FTDI chip will still show up as a FTDI serial port to the PC, regardless of the ATMega32 being programmed, in reset, erased, or soldered off completely.

Comment: You are probably right, I now read about HID and I need to put BootloadHID in atmega32a bootloader memory space, I hope that it will then find it as HID(Human Interface Device). But I checked with university professor, schematics are all good. @Justme

Comment: I will try it and keep you posted

Comment: BootloadHID is a software bit-bang USB stack and it is only a bootloader for updating the application code. While useful, it does not make your application to be a HID device. And you would need to connect PC USB directly to ATMega pins, which means that your hardware must be built compatible with BootloadHID and USB. For example you might need a certain frequency crystal and have the AVR run on 3.3V supply so you don't damage the USB port of your PC.

Comment: I had an idea of flashing bootloader HID in ATMega32 via USBasp and AVRDUDE it has all pins extracted from dip-40 of atmega32a-pu. But how I put that in those first mcu memory blocks which are bootloader space, and not just flash it in mcu memory.